# Move site up one directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have moved my site up one directory and would like old links to 'divert' to the new location.

The old directory was `/project/` and the files that were in that directory are now in `/`

For example. I would like `www.example.com/project/page.php` to link to `www.example.com/page.php` and for the browser url to change so that the user is aware that the page has moved.

This is in my .htaccess file in `/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/project/?(.*)$ /$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

However this goes to `www.example.com` instead of `www.example.com/page.php`
What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing in all rules I think you need to add

```
#it should be now
RewriteBase /

#if code files are in projects folder
RewriteBase /projects/
```

In this way, no need to attach folder name in all RewriteRule.